# Proving this simple equality

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

$${\sum}_{t=1}^T(t-\bar{t})^2=\sum_{t=1}^T t^2 - T\bar{t}^2$$

Is there any special property going on here? I cant seem to work around it.

$\bar{t}$ is the mean

$T$ is the last $t$ in sequence $t=1,2,3,...T$

Edit: Sorry I was vague, I assumed this was a very simple equality so that people who knew it would be able to recognize it immediately.

Comment: It looks like "magic": what're $\;t,\overline t,T\;$ ? The sum is from what to *what*? What's going on here?

Comment: You say inequality, but you provided us with an equality. Also, while I suppose that $\bar{t}$ is the mean of $t$, I couldn't figure out what $T$ meant.

Comment: @DonAntonio, my best guess it's something about $t$ being values of a sample, $\bar{t}$ is the mean of said sample and the summation is over all the values. I guess that if you suppose $T$ is the number of elements in the sample, it will work, but, as you said, it looks like "magic" the way it is now

Comment: I surmise, $T$ is the number of terms, and $\overline{t}$ is the mean. $$\sum (t-\overline{t})^2 = \sum (t^2 -2t\overline{t} + \overline{t}^2) = \left(\sum t^2\right) - 2\overline{t}\left(\sum t\right) + T\overline{t}^2.$$ Now, $\sum t = T\overline{t}$. But one **really** should properly index etc.

Comment: Well done, @sggd. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Hey ive edited and also explained the sloppiness, I apologize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\bar t$ is the mean of $T$ samples $t_i$ ($i=1,\ldots, T$), that is $$\bar t=\frac 1T\sum_{k=1}^T t_i,$$
then 
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^T(t_i-\bar t)^2 & =\sum_{k=1}^T(t_i^2-2\bar tt_i+\bar t^2)\\&=\sum_{i=1}^Tt_i^2-2\bar t\sum_{i=1}^Tt_i+T\cdot \bar t^2\\&=\sum_{i=1}^Tt_i^2-2T\bar t^2+T\bar t^2\\&=\sum_{i=1}^Tt_i^2-T\bar t^2.\end{align}$$